# How to get difference between dates in the SAME column in oracle using only SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

If I have a simple table with a column that has type DATE like this:

```
START_DATE
06/02/2013 05:30:00 AM
06/05/2013 12:00:00 PM
06/10/2013 01:45:00 AM
```

Is it possible to get the hours to the next START_DATE such as something like:

```
START_DATE                 HOURS_TO_NEXT_START
06/02/2013 05:30:00 AM     78.5
06/05/2013 12:00:00 PM     109.75
06/10/2013 01:45:00 AM     0
```

Note that this result is OK too:

```
START_DATE                 HOURS_FROM_PREVIOUS_START
06/02/2013 05:30:00 AM     0
06/05/2013 12:00:00 PM     78.5
06/10/2013 01:45:00 AM     109.75
```

Since at the end of the day the hours numbers are what I am really interested in...

I am pretty sure that CONNECT BY is involved in traversing this list recursively to check time difference to the next start date but I think I need help actually doing this. All the examples I see on CONNECT BY seem to address traversing a concurrent list.

Comment: Wouldn't the second example actually be `HOURS_FROM_PREVIOUS_START`?  I'd be wondering where the last row disappeared to....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
select start_date,
       (lead(start_date,1) over (order by start_date)-start_date)*24 
            as hours_to_next_start
from myTable
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0107e/1).

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. 

Thanks for the answer and my introduction to this new, to me, command.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just found an answer to group calc by ids

Just have to add the following

```
select start_date,
   (lead(start_date,1) over (*PARTITION BY ID* order by start_date)-start_date)*24 
        as hours_to_next_start
from myTable
```

Thanks again